# API Gateway custom authorizer

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm new to API Gateway. I try to use the "custom authorizer". I followed below document and used sample code that website provided.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html

The "Lambda Authorizer of the TOKEN type" is work.

```
curl -v -H 'x-custom-auth: xxxxx" https://xxxxx.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/Prod/
```

For the "Lambda Authorizer of the REQUEST type", I can input header, queryValue1, stageValue1 and accountId for testing via aws console.

But...

I'm confused about the "request type" and did not know how to pass the queryValue1, stageValue1 and accountId to API Gateway.

Can anyone help me to figure it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of which type of Authorizer you use, API Gateway will receive the same headers and parameters that you originally sent.

Your Authorizer cannot modify the original request details (but it include an auth `context` which API Gateway can also read).

In the example you're referencing:

```
if (headers.HeaderAuth1 === "headerValue1"
    && queryStringParameters.QueryString1 === "queryValue1"
    && stageVariables.StageVar1 === "stageValue1"
    && requestContext.accountId === "123456789012") {
    callback(null, generateAllow('me', event.methodArn));
}  else {
    callback("Unauthorized");
}
```

What they're saying is that the `REQUEST` authorizer is expecting specific values in the request object:

- If all the values match, the authorizer will `Allow` the request to continue. API Gateway will receive the same request object (with all the same parameters).
- If not all the values match, the authorizer will `Deny` the request returning `403 Unauthorized`; API Gateway will not receive the request.

Each of the properties in the example are sourced in the following ways:

- `AccountId` is set automatically by AWS
- `StageVar1` comes from the deployed API's stage settings (API Name > Stages > Stage Name > Stage Variables)
- `HeaderAuth` and `QueryString1` are sent by the HTTP client (e.g. `curl`)

Comment: Thank you for your kind assistance.

I failed to pass QueryString1, StageVar1 and accountId via "curl -d" Or I should set QueryString1 in "Method Request", StageVar1 in Stage and accountId in Mapping Template?

Comment: AccountId is set for you automatically. Stage variables are set-up by you after deploying the API to a stage (visit the stage's settings). Query string and headers are passed by the http client (curl)

Comment: Thank you for helping me

Comment: No worries, I'll edit the answer with the stuff from the comments